# Kerberos authentication fails when local password is expired

Tags: linux, kerberos, pam, sles

I am using pam_krb5 with local accounts (Linux) for AD password authentication. Things are working great, users are able to authenticate with both AD and local passwords.

I am having a problem though, when the local password expires Kerberos authentication fails and prompts the user to change their local password. The issue is that most users cannot remember their local password, and my workaround so far has been to temporarily disable local password change enforcement.

Is there a way to have pam_krb5 ignore expired local passwords, or at least configure PAM to prioritize Kerberos passwords over local?

My research lead me to believe it has something to do with common-auth, which I have provided below:

```
auth    required        pam_env.so
auth    sufficient      pam_unix2.so
auth    requisite       pam_succeed_if.so user ingroup access_www
auth    sufficient      pam_krb5.so     use_first_pass
auth    required        pam_deny.so
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put `pam_krb5` before `pam_unix2` (and keep the `use_first_pass` on the latter entry).

Comment: Gave that a try, got the same result with being prompted to change the expired password.

Comment: I've resolved the problem. I needed to make this exact change to common-account instead of common-auth. Thanks for the suggestion!